# Question concering lim sup and lim inf

Tags: real-analysis

I'm using Elementary Analysis by Ross.

I'm trying to prove that if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} s_n = \infty$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n = \infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = \infty$.

I really don't know how to start this. The author says its easy, but all he's given us at this point of the book is the following definition.

10.6 Deﬁnition. Let $(s_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R$.

We deﬁne $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sup\{s_n : n>N\}$$ and $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n = \lim_{N\to\infty} \inf\{s_n : n>N\}$$

Note that in this deﬁnition we do not restrict $(s_n)_n$ to be bounded. However, we adopt the following conventions.

If $(s_n)_n$ is not bounded above, $\sup\{s_n : n>N\} =+\infty$ for all $N$ and we decree $\limsup_{n\to\infty}s_n =+\infty$.

Likewise, if $(s_n)_n$ is not bounded below, $\inf\{s_n : n>N\} = −\infty$ for all $N$ and we decree $\liminf_{n\to\infty} s_n = -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\inf_{k\geq n}s_k\leq s_n.$$

Comment: Thanks for this as well. Got it down.

Answer (score 1):

It is sufficient to look at $\liminf_n s_n = \infty$.

Note that $\liminf_n s_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \ge n} s_k$.

Choose $L>0$ and pick $N$ such that if $n \ge N$ then $\inf_{k \ge n} s_k \ge L$ and,
in particular, $s_n \ge L$. Hence
$s_n \to \infty$.

Comment: My only question now is, if we need the other condition. That is, why is lim sup s_n = infinity essential in this problem. And do issues arrive if it is not true. Thanks

Comment: Since $\limsup_n s_n \ge \liminf_n s_n$ the first condition is superfluous.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate the help!. I believe the author just wanted to emphasis that lim s_n is meaningful whenever the lim sup s_n = lim inf s_n.